# Loop with simple counter malfunctioning?

Tags: c, string, loops, if-statement, for-loop

I have a program that takes a char array and calls the function convert. The function determines whether the character is a letter or number. The program is supposed to output the first letter it finds in the string. and the first numbers it finds in the string. My loop to stop looking for letters after it finds one isn't working.

Any thoughts?
Code is written in C using the Borland Compiler.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int convert (char array[],char **);

int main()
{
    int intval; 
    char array[512], *charptr;

    printf("Input a string that starts with a series of decimal digits:\n>");
    while ( gets( array ) != NULL ){
        intval = convert(array, &charptr );
        printf ("Intval contains %d, Charptr contains '%s'\n", intval, charptr);
    }
    system("pause");

    return 0;


}
int convert (char array[],char ** charptr)
{
    int i, x, c = 0;
    char b[512];
    for (i=0;i<strlen(array);i++){

        if (isalpha(array[i]))
        {
            if(c >= 1){ 
                *charptr = &array[i];
                c++;
                }
            else 
                break;


        }
        else if ( isdigit(array[i]))
                x = 10*x + array[i] - '0';

     }

    return  x;
}
```

UPDATE:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>


int convert (char array[],char ** charptr);



int main()
{
    int intval; 
    char array[512], *charptr;

    printf("Input a string that starts with a series of decimal digits:\n>");
    while ( gets( array ) != NULL ){
        intval = convert(array, &charptr );
        printf ("Intval contains %d, Charptr contains '%s'\n", intval, charptr);
    }
    system("pause");

    return 0;


}
int convert (char array[],char ** charptr)
{
    int i, x, c;
    char b[512];
   for (i=0;array[i] != 0;i++){
        if ( isdigit(array[i]))

                x = 10*x + array[i] - '0';
        else if (isalpha(array[i]))
        {
            c++;
            if(c >= 1){ 
                *charptr = &array[i];

            }  
        }

    }

    return  x;
}
```

Comment: did you step through the code with the debugger?

Comment: Hint: `if(c >= 1){` is never true.

Comment: 1. charptr should be allocated before used
2. this is bad:     for (i=0;i<strlen(array);i++) // calls strlen for every character in the string
   a bit better:    for (i=0;array[i] != 0;i++)   // quits the loop when it hits string zero
Think of variables x and c a little more.

Comment: You can write this code more efficiently using `scanf()`. Don't ever use `gets()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a logic error. `c` is initialized to `0`. There is a line to increment `c` but it is inside an `if` block that will never be true.

```
        if(c >= 1){ 
            *charptr = &array[i];
            c++;
            }
```

Catch 22???

Perhaps you meant to use:

```
int convert (char array[],char ** charptr)
{
    int i, x, c = 0;
    char b[512];
    for (i=0;i<strlen(array);i++){

        if (isalpha(array[i]))
        {
                // No need for checking the value of c
                // return as soon you find an alphabet.
                *charptr = &array[i];
                break;    
        }
        else if ( isdigit(array[i]))
                // If you are looking for an alphabet only,
                // why do you have this block of code???
                x = 10*x + array[i] - '0';
    }

    return  x;
}
```

**Update**

Perhaps, this is what you are looking for.

```
int convert (char array[], char ** charptr)
{
   size_t i;
   int x = 0;
   size_t len = strlen(array);

   // Set charptr to NULL in case there are no letters in the input.
   *charptr = NULL;
   for (i=0;i<len;i++){

      if ( isalpha(array[i]))
      {
         *charptr = &array[i];
         return x;
      }
      else if ( isdigit(array[i]))
      {
         x = 10*x + array[i] - '0';
      }
   }

   return x;
}
```

Comment: @R Sahu i need the second block of code to print the first numbers it finds. For example it the user inputs 274ADAMS It would print the first 3 numbers then the first letter 'A'.

Comment: @R Sahu did this work for you? I tried useing this code and it still doesn't stop after the first letter.

Comment: It will stop after it find a letter AND a number. If you want to stop after the first letter regardless of whether you found a number or not, the function needs to be modified.

Comment: @R Sahu how would I modify it to to stop regardless of whether it finds number or not?

Comment: @R Sahu It still doesn't work. Maybe something in my main function is wrong?

Comment: Perhaps. What's your input?

Comment: @R Sahu my input is 274ADAZ

Comment: How would the input affect the loop? I tried tweaking stuff and now it just prints the last character only.

Comment: @Himinguiand1930, I had a small error in my code. The line `charptr = NULL;` should've been `*charptr = NULL;`. With that change, it works for me. See [working code](http://ideone.com/oZiWCf).

Comment: @R Sahu the working code that you posted prints all of the letters not just the first one. I need the code to just print the first letter that it finds not all of them

Comment: Then, you need to use `printf ("Intval contains %d, Charptr contains '%c'\n", intval, *charptr);`

Comment: @R Sahu when I use *charptr it gives me a runtime error

Answer (score 0):

```
int scanString(char array[],char * charptr)
{
    int len = strlen(array);
    int digs = 0;
    int x = 0;
    *charptr = 0; 
    for (int i=0;i<len;i++){

        if (charptr == 0 && isalpha(array[i]))
        {
                *charptr = array[i];
        }
        else if (digs == 0 && isdigit(array[i])){

                x = array[i] - '0';
               digs = 1;
       }
       if(digs > 0 && charptr != 0)
          break;
    }

    return  x;
}
```

the spec says return the first character found so changed the charptr.

Comment: this needs, at the beginning to set 'x' and '*charptr' to indicate the related item not found in the string.  So if it is not in the string, the caller will know that the item was not found.  if I were doing it, I would gen an enum for the 4 possible return conditions, pass in another ptr to a digit, and proceed accordingly

Comment: done - i guess thats why he multiplied by 10 - to distinguish between found and 0 = not found